# A problem with equating the work of a conservative electrical force (electrical field) to the change in kinetic energy in order to calculate velocity

Tags: energy, electric-fields, energy-conservation

I have a problem when trying to calculate the velocity of a particle after a conservative force (electrical field) has been applied to it.

Basically, what i know is this: $-ΔE_k = ΣW_{conservative}$. Here's an example of the equation. I have a positively charged particle that had work done on it by a positive electrical field (basically accelerating it). The amount of work done on it is as shown below:

$$m = 10^{-4}kg$$
$$v_0=0$$
$$-ΔE_k = ΣW_{conservative}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} mv_0^2-\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = 0.5 \cdot10^{-6}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} mv^2=0.5\cdot10^{-6}$$
$$v^2=-10^{-6}/m.$$

And as you can see, this is not possible.

So, my question is what am I doing wrong? How can I equate them? This is also a problem with negative work when dealing with negatively charged particles.

Comment: How did you arrive at the work being 0.5 x 10$^{-6}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John Darby pointed out, work equals change in kinetic energy, but it is the ***net*** work done on an object that equals its change in kinetic energy, not just work. This is the work-energy theorem. I emphasize the work ***net*** because the work done on an object can be positive or negative or a combination of both.

> I have a positively charged particle that had work done on it by a
> positive electrical field (basically accelerating it). The amount of
> work done on it is.

For simplicity, assume a constant electric field $\overrightarrow E$. Then the positive charge experiences a force of $\overrightarrow F=q\overrightarrow E$. By convention, the direction of the electric field is the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. Therefore, in this case, $\overrightarrow F$ is positive.

Since movement (displacement) $\overrightarrow d$ of the charge is in the same direction as the force applied by the field (repulsive), the work done by the field displacing the charge, where $\theta$ = the angle between $\overrightarrow F$ and $\overrightarrow d$, is

$$W=+q\overrightarrow E. \overrightarrow d=qEd\cos\theta$$

$$\theta = 0$$

$$W=qEd$$

And the work is positive. The work-energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Since in this example the only force acting on the charge is the electric field, the work done by the field is the net work and equals

$$+qEd=\frac {1}{2}mv_{f}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mv_{o}^2=\frac {1}{2}mv_{f}^{2}$$

*Note that the increase in kinetic energy is at the expense of an equal decrease in electrical potential energy of the positive charge.*

> This is also a problem with negative work when dealing with negatively
> charged particles.

If a negative charge is placed in the field, then it will experience a force of $\overrightarrow F=-q\overrightarrow E$ causing the negative charge to move in the direction opposite to the field, but still in the same direction as the force of the field on the negative charge (attraction). But now the displacement of the charge is  opposite the direction of the field.  The work done on the negative charge is

$$W=-q\overrightarrow E.\overrightarrow d=-qEd\cos\theta$$

$$\theta =180$$
$$\cos\theta = -1$$

$$W=qEd$$

So the work done on the negative charge is again positive, and the change in kinetic energy is positive. Once again, the increase in kinetic energy of the negative charge equals the decrease in its electrical potential energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't quite solve my problem. I now face a problem where I need to equate the {potential difference}*{charge of an electron} (which is the amount of work needed to move the electron from one electrically charged plate to another) to the change in kinetic energy. The problem is, the work is negative and I cannot equate it to the change in kinetic energy because velocity is squared. that's really the problem. the electrical field the electron is passing through is a positive one.

Comment: @YuvalRoth I will update to respond.

Comment: I'm basing this on We = -e*Va-->b - So , because the electron is negative and the potential difference is positive, I get negative work. the only thing i can think of is maybe the potential difference is negative as well... maybe because the electron moves from a state of low energy to high.. idk.. if you could clear things up for me that'd help a lot.

Comment: @YuvalRoth are you talking about the work done moving the electron from the positive plate to the negative plate, or from the negative plate to the positive plate.

Comment: I have 2 positive plates. The left one is charged Q, the right one is charged 3Q, so the electrical field in between them is 2Q/ε0*A (A is the area in Gauss's law) to the left. The question asked at what velocity do you need to release an electron from the right plate for it to reach the left plate. So, I want to equate the work it takes for the electron to move from the right plate to the left plate to the change in kinetic energy to get the velocity.

Comment: @YuvalRoth Whoa! None of this was in your original post! It's a whole different question.

Comment: Haha... well... is that something you can help me with? or should i just make a different question about it and post the entire question

Comment: @YuvalRoth I'd make it a different question, but be careful not to present it as a homework and exercise question.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out! I mistakenly wrote We = -e*Vab instead of We = -e*(-Vab). What I didn't consider is that delta V(voltage) is {Vfinish-Vinitial} and in order for it to be {Vinitial-Vfinish} I need to add a minus beforehand which turns my work into positive! everything fits now!

Comment: @YuvalRoth I tried to tell you the work is positive when I wrote:$$W=-q\overrightarrow E.\overrightarrow d=-qEd\cos\theta$$

$$\theta =180$$
$$\cos\theta = -1$$

$$W=qEd$$ The only difference is I used $Ed$ which is the same as $V$ for a parallel plate capacitor.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, and thanks to your explanation - that the work should indeed be positive, I was able to narrow down where I was going wrong (It's always forgetting to add that damned minus!). Thank you for the time and effort spent into explaining it to me! You really helped me a lot! have a great day!

Comment: @Yuval Roth you’re welcome. It’s always best when you figure it out on your own

Comment: @YuvalRoth Just to be clear, the work done by the electric field when the electron moves from the 3Q plate to the Q plate in your example is in fact negative. That is why it requires the electron to have an initial velocity because the negative work done by the field takes kinetic energy away from the electron. If this is not clear to you, let's continue this in Chat.

Comment: Yes, it is clear, thank you. In this instance it had to be a positive value because what I was calculating was how much initial velocity I had to give the particle in order to reach the destination with 0 velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship  $-ΔE_k = ΣW_{conservative}$ is incorrect; work is the change in kinetic energy: $ΔE_k = ΣW$.  See a basic physics test such as one by Halliday and Resnick.  You may have confused kinetic and potential energy for the work done by a conservative forces.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

There are actually two mistakes here - the one you're asking about, and one other.

The first one is that if work is done on the particle then the kinetic energy of the particle must **increase** rather than decrease. So the correct equation is:
$$\frac{1}{2} mv^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 = \text{work done}$$
The second mistake is that you don't have any units for the work done, which means even once the equation is round the right way, you'll end up with a meaningless answer $v^2=10^{-6}/m.$ ($10^{-6}$ *whats* divided by m)?

What are the units of the work? Is it $10^{-6}$ Joules $(=10^{-6}kg{\times}\frac{metres^2}{seconds^2})$? Or something else?

Comment: “The first one is that if work is done on the particle then the kinetic energy of the particle must **increase** rather than decrease”. It is essential to say “net work. You should edit your answer